# Do ROC curves require probabilities?

Tags: roc, multi-class, softmax

In the binary case, the implementation of ROC curve in `torchmetrics` automatically applies a sigmoid when it detects logit inputs (i.e. when the values of scores are not within [0,1]). I have several problems with this:

1. Nominally, ROC requires a 1D list of scores, which then gets sorted and thresholded. Applying any monotonic bijective function to the scores won't change the ROC. However, if our model scores are not probabilities, but pairs of classification weights (appropriate for `CrossEntropyLoss`), then the classifier is essentially invariant under an overall bias `[w0,w1]->[w0+b,w1+b]` because `Softmax` of them depends only on `w1-w0`. This means that I could add a random bias `b` to each of my predictions and still get the same loss and the same accuracy. Meanwhile, the ROC could drastically change because if I were to extract the values of `w1` and sort them, their order could be totally different after adding the random bias. Why is this not a problem for regular implementations of ROC that take logits? To me it seems like the only valid way of doing it without applying `Softmax` is to apply the threshold to `w1-w0`, not just one of the weights. Simply using `sigmoid` the way `torchmetrics` does it can't possibly fix this issue.
2. In the multi-class case things get even hairier. ROC is known to be invariant under transformations that preserve the ranking of the scores. `Softmax` is one such transformation. So you would think that if the binary ROC works fine with pre-softmax logits, multi-class one-vs-rest ROC should also work well with raw scores. However, in practice I found that the ROC changes drastically after applying `Softmax` to a multi-class output. What gives?
3. My current theory is that due to how neural networks are trained, binary classification weights typically end up being close opposites of each other, `w1 ~ -w0`. This means that it actually *is* enough to look at only `w1` to infer the result of the classification, and thresholding on it without `Softmax` is safe (only approximately though). Meanwhile, in the multi-class case there is no such simple relationship, and you really do need `Softmax` to get rid of the inconsistent bias across different outputs. Even though `Softmax` doesn't change the rankings of the scores within each entry, it factors out the translational symmetry inherent in `CrossEntropyLoss`, which is necessary before you apply a threshold.

Is my intuition in (3) correct? Is there a source that explains these subtleties? Should I actually always be using `Softmax` even in the binary case?

Edit:

as an example of how softmax affects the ROC (this is a binary classification case with 100% accuracy):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import softmax, expit
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

scores=np.array([[0.5,1.0],
                 [5.5,1.5]])
labels=[1,0]
# Verify accuracy
print("Acc =",np.mean((np.argmax(scores,axis=1)==labels)))
# AUC using raw scores
print("AUC =",roc_auc_score(labels, scores[:,1]))
# AUC after applying a sigmoid (doesn't change ROC)
print("AUC =",roc_auc_score(labels, expit(scores)[:,1]))
# AUC after softmax (changes ranking of scores across entries)
print("AUC =",roc_auc_score(labels, softmax(scores, axis=1)[:,1]))
```

output:

```
Acc = 1.0
AUC = 0.0
AUC = 0.0
AUC = 1.0
```

Comment: Which ROC implementation accepts logits as input? I don't think I've seen that before. Are you sure they aren't internally applying the sigmoid transformation?

Comment: @shadowtalker I'm actually not sure and am confused by the descriptions. Sklearn says "Target scores, can either be probability estimates of the positive class, confidence values, or non-thresholded measure of decisions (as returned by “decision_function” on some classifiers)." This to me sounds like it allows raw scores, no? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html

Comment: You're right, it does. But thinking about this a bit more, it makes perfect sense. See Dave's answer.

Comment: When speaking about ROC for a binary classification problem being invariant under strictly increasing transformations, it's assumed that the model produces _one_ output, a confidence for the positive class, and that is what your transformation applies to.  Your example violates that, and softmax isn't "monotone increasing" in the positive predictions.

Comment: Cross-entropy loss _is_ log-loss for binary classification, but it sounds like for your package of interest it produces something else.  Multiclass ROC isn't particularly well-defined, so all bets are off there.

Comment: @BenReiniger ok this is what I needed to hear. So basically whenever I produce multiple classification scores, I *have* to use softmax before computing ROC. I've seen way too many examples online that completely neglect to state this.

Answer (score 3):

(At least in the binary case…)

Some software might complain if you don’t give values between zero and one, but this is not a requirement to calculate ROC curves or the area under the curve. ROC curves do not change when you apply increasing transformations. They only consider ranks. For instance, subtract ten from every prediction or square every prediction (assuming the predictions are not negative), and watch the ROC curve remain unchanged.

If you don't use an increasing transformation, then all bets are off.

Comment: never mind, you're totally right!

Comment: See my point 2. The ROC curve absolutely does change in the multi-class case, I've seen it in practice.

Comment: @level1807 I’d like to see an example of this.

Comment: Perhaps I'll give a contrived example of a binary classifier. Let's say we have two entries with 2 classification weights each: `[[0.5,1.],[5.5,1.5]]` and true labels `[1,0]`. The accuracy is 100%. Without Softmax, the ROC curve function would receive `[1.,1.5]` and the result is `fpr=[1,1], tpr=[0,1]`. After Softmax, however, the scores are `[[0.3775, 0.6225],[0.9820, 0.0180]]`, the ROC function receives `[0.6225,0.0180]`, and the result is `fpr=[0,1],tpr=[1,1]`, which is the exact opposite.

Comment: @level1807 Please put your example in some Python or R code so I can follow exactly what you’re doing. Binary ROC curves should not change when monotonic transformations are applied. You can add this code in a edit to your original question post.

Comment: @Dave added to post

Comment: @level1807 Check the `scores[:, 1]` and `softmax(scores, axis = 1)[:,1]`. That is not an increasing transformation (I've edited my answer to clarify that it is increasing functions, not just monotonic functions, that preserve ROC curves). I'm not sure why it isn't an increasing transformation (I expected it to be), but it changes the order.

Comment: "The only consider ranks" — ranks across classes, or across samples? I agree that adding 10 to every prediction won't change the ROC, but adding 10 to one sample and subtracting 10 from another sample will. This is what my post is about, since Softmax neutralizes actions like this. But then I'm confused why existing packages say it's okay to use ROC with raw scores.

Comment: ok, so, walking away from semantics, if we agree that softmax changes the order, then certainly it can't *ever* be okay to apply ROC to a single column of raw scores, right? Because classification works is by comparing the two weights to *each other*, not to a threshold.